# ¿Relaciones incorrectas de modelo Entidad-Relación?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Muy buenas, tengo duda sobre la relación de la tabla dirección con la tabla cliente, no se si hice bien en agregar otra para poder tener identificados a los clientes por direcciones, tomando en cuenta que un cliente puede tener varias direcciónes (esto por ser comerciante, podría tener más de 1 negocio), y una dirección va a tener muchos clientes. Podría colocar unicamente el Id_dir en la tabla cliente? y que me comentaran si el resto de relaciones estan bien, muchas gracias de antemano.[image: Modelo ERD]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Entiendo que te debates entre estas dos formas diferentes de modelar tu problema:

[image: Opciones de modelado del problema]

Ninguna de las dos es incorrecta, simplemente dan respuesta a realidades diferentes. De ahí tu duda y que se piense que la respuesta correcta dependa de la opinión de cada cual. Ambas tienen ventajas e inconvenientes y, dependerá de la información que manejes, simplemente una se adaptará a tu problema mejor que la otra.

**Primer modelo**

Estaría genial si varios clientes compartieran la misma dirección física. De esta forma evitarías almacenar la misma dirección postal un montón de veces. Podrías utilizarlo para reutilizar el nombre de las calles, códigos postales o nombres de poblaciones pero, para portal, planta y puerta igual ya sería excesivo, aunque no necesariamente incorrecto.

Funcionaría muy bien si el Ayuntamiento modificara el nombre de una calle, pero sería bastante incómodo si un cliente se traslada de ubicación. Tendrías que registrar una nueva dirección y reasignársela al cliente. Habría que modificar el dato en la relación, nunca en la entidad. Pues, modificando la entidad, podrías afectar a más de un cliente.

**Segundo modelo**

El campo `id_cliente` de la relación `r` se propaga a `direccion`, permitiendo así que un mismo cliente pueda tener varias direcciones. Por tanto, es una ventaja de ambos modelos. Con éste en concreto, ahorras una tabla y las direcciones son específicas para cada cliente. Si cambias una, no la modificas en todos los clientes, lo que te permite simplificar este proceso.

**Conclusión**

Tal vez la mejor solución sea un híbrido entre ambos modelos: una entidad con poblaciones y códigos postales y, si dispones de recursos, otra con el callejero de cada población y hasta los números de calle. Así evitarías que te facilitaran direcciones inexistentes.

Como ves, el modelado de datos no es 1+1=2, blanco o negro. Hay diferentes formas de abordar un mismo problema en función de los recursos que quieras dedicarle, las restricciones que quieras implementar y lo simple o versátil que quieras que resulte. Sobre todo, de cara a mantenerlo en el futuro.

Espero no haberte liado más. Cualquier duda, por favor, déjamela en los comentarios.

Comment: Justamente era el inconveniente que tenía, tomé tu punto de vista y lo adapté a mi BD, te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya resultado útil. ¿Por qué solución optaste? ¿La simplificada o la híbrida?

Comment: Sería un híbrido, agregue el Id_dir a la tabla clientes, y en esta tabla agregue un campo para poder agregar un valor de refrencia para poder tener una dirección exacta y a la vez tener agrupados a los clientes por ciertas ubicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Si dices que una misma dirección puede pertenecer a varios clientes entonces lo tienes bien, ya que sería una relación M:N y se crearía una tabla intermedia.

Pero si un cliente puede tener una o varias direcciones y cada dirección pertenece a un cliente solo, entonces yo pondría el atributo id_cliente en la tabla DIRECCION, al ser una relación 1:N, se propaga la clave de clientes a direccion.